# Error: An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL (Error while integrating Mapbox to my NextJS project)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mapbox

I am trying to integrate Mapbox with my nextjs application. Unfortunately I keep getting the same error in the console.

1. I tried copy pasting the access token directly in the code
2. I tried loading the env variable from .env file still no luck and same error.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_TOKEN: .....

//my component:

 <ReactMapGL
        id="ComplianceMap"
        {...viewState}
        mapboxAccessToken={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
        }}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mystyle"
```

3. I also tried adding the env variable in next.config.js:

[using next.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfDw9.png)

```
//Here is my component:

import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';
 <ReactMapGL
        id="ComplianceMap"
        {...viewState}
        mapboxAccessToken={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
        }}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/netfreak29/clk1998y7016r01qv27upbh05"
        initialViewState={{
          longitude: SAMPLE_ENTITY_DATA.centroidLongitude,
          latitude: SAMPLE_ENTITY_DATA.centroidLatitude,
          zoom: 16,
        }}
        interactiveLayerIds={getInteractiveLayers()}
        onMove={(evt) => setViewState(evt.viewState)}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        onClick={handleMouseClick}
      >
```

How can I make this work? I tried looking on the stackoverflow but people are recommending to change the prop mapboxApiAccessToken to mapboxAccessToken which I did. Not sure what is wrong

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the code. It's probably something really silly. So i will ask the obviously silly question, have you tried logging the environment variable? just to make sure it's being loaded.